# How to completely stop the jQuery UI dialog from opening if the tab is shifted?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

I want to open a jQuery UI dialog box (whose content is loaded via ajax) within a jQuery UI tab.

#### Scenario:

I have two tabs in the page. If I click on the overlay link (for the modal dialog) in one tab, and during the loading of the dialog (which is not yet visible - an ajax call is happening), I click on the other tab, I want the tab to shift, and the overlay from tab 1 to be removed. At present, it is getting loaded into tab 2.

How to stop the old dialog from tab 1 showing up in tab 2?

dialog("close") & dialog("destroy") doent fix the issue.

Appreciate the quick response.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So your dialog is not being shown until an ajax call is completed? Is that right?

If so you could check in the oncompleted function of your ajax call that tab 1 is still selected. If not, then don't show the dialog.

```
$.get("example.com/foo", null, function (data, status) {

    if ($(".tab1.ui-selected").length == 1) {
        // open the dialog
    } else {
        // do nothing.
    }


} );
```

Comment: If there isn't a good reason why the ajax call needs to be in the open event of the dialog I'd consider moving it as above.  The example above could also be extended to handle the case where the AJAX call fails - e.g. you don't show a broken dialog, but a error message instead.

Comment: sorry ben, i have removed the above comment.Actually ajax call is via the dialog inbuilt functionality.(option "source" is used)

Comment: @stackoverflow <<My questions are modified from stack overflow folks & it changes the context of the issue>>>